# How to input a vector as variable to a function?

Tags: r

In one of my homework, I am asked to print the prices of a bond over 2015,2016,2017,2018. 
Since 2015,2016 have 252 trading days, 2017 with 251 and 2018 with 250, I need to write an if statement.
Here is my attempt:

```
plt <- function(a) {
  if (a == 2015) {
    x <- 1:252
  }
  else if (a == 2016) {
    x <- 1:252
  }
  else if (a == 2017) {
    x <- 1:251
  } else {
    x <- 1:250
  }
  plot(x=x, y=data[data$Year == a, 5], type="l", col="red")
}
```

However,when I input

```
function(c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018))
```

only draft of 2015 shows up and R returns

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (a == 2015) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In data$Year == a :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

If I input these years seperately, it gives four perfect plots.

Comment: Do you have the date associated with each price? If so, I think that printing those would be better. If not, then what you probably want to visualize is the distributions of the prices (by year), in which case a scatterplot is less suited to the task than other options like boxplot, histogram, or frequency polygon.

Comment: Your `if` statement works fine, but it only runs on the first element. Put it in a `for` loop, `for (i in 1:length(a)) { ...your code with a[i] instead of a...}`.

Comment: Could you provide some information on the object called `data` please?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, but it's great that you have provided some code.  First I wonder if instead of  `function(c(2015,2016,2017,2018)` you mean `plt(2015,2016,2017,2018)`.  Instead of `if`  you probably want `ifelse`  which will use a vectorized approach.

Comment: Thank you guys. The problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that instead of `function(c(2015,2016,2017,2018)`you mean `plt(c(2015,2016,2017,2018)`.  If I'm wrong on that I'll delete the answer.

Let's start the function.  In this case, `a == c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)`.

In your function you ask, does `a == 2015`.  No it does not; `a` is a vector of length 4 as shown above. 2015 in r is a scalar or a vector of length 1.

Does `a == 2016`? No and likewise for 2017 and 2018.  So none of your if conditions are ever true and hence your `plot()` can't work because `x` is never created.

Instead you might want to rewrite your code to take `a` and work on each element.
Also  you might want to simplify by creating 
`a_length <- c(252, 252, 251, 205)`rather than writing everything out.

At that point you can use a for loop or `lapply()` to get the plots.